# How to determine how much of the variation in a binary dependent variable can be determined from a set of independent variables?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova, statistical-power

I'm working with a dataset of legislative voting results in the brazilian Chamber of Deputies. I have a list of votes (mapped as 1 and 0 for Yes and No), like:

`| deputy_name | rollcall_1 | rollcall_2 | ... | rollcall_n |
| ----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ... | ---------- |
| John        | 0          | 1          | ... | 1          |
| Mary        | 0          | 0          | ... | 1          |
| Paul        | 1          | 1          | ... | 0          |
| ...         | ...        | ...        | ... | ...        |`

Based on this, I splitted the rollcalls in 2 arbitrary groups (before and after), and used a metric (Optimal Classification) that maps all deputies in a single axis, with similar deputies close together. I also have a column (`changed_position`) that says if a deputy entered/left the government's coalition (i.e. she was opposition and became government or vice-versa). The data looks like:

`| deputy_name | before | after | changed_position |
| ----------- | ------ | ----- | ---------------- |
| John        | 0.3    | 0.8   | TRUE             |
| Mary        | 0.7    | 0.6   | FALSE            |
| Paul        | 1      | 1     | FALSE            |
| ...         | ...    | ...   | ...              |`

I've been trying to build a model to predict `changed_position` using `before` and `after` (and a few variations, like `after - before`, etc.), but I've been unable to find a good one. My hypothesis is that it's because there's not enough information on just these variables to be able to predict well (i.e. my model has high bias).

It seems that ANOVA would be a good way to test how much variation in `changed_position` can be attributed to `before` and `after`, but unfortunately I need a non-parametric test.

Andrew Ng suggests plotting the learning curve. If I get something like:

[image: High bias learning curve]

That would mean that I have a high bias problem. Unfortunately, that requires (as far as I know) that I should define what the "desired performance" is, which I would like to avoid.

How can I determine how much of the variation in `changed_position` can be explained by `before` and `after`?

Comment: Parts of this question touch broadly on huge subjects concerning regression and model building. Other parts seem to hint that your question is not about `mtcars` at all, but about a dataset and context for which you provide no specific information. Either way, this is not a good fit to our format. Please consult our [help] for more information on what kinds of questions we can answer and how to formulate them so they can get good answers.

Comment: @whuber Sorry. I've editted the question with the dataset I'm using, which hopefully makes my question clearer.

Comment: Thank you for providing more detail. Please bear with me and consider explaining what you mean by "enough to determine." As stated, that's not a statistical question: either the two columns have a one-to-one correspondence with (that is, determine) the values of `changed_position` or they do not. The latter will occur when two deputies have identical values of their variables but different values of `changed_position`. In that situation, many people would be interested in assessing the rate at which a model makes prediction errors. In this context, what would "enough to determine" mean?

Comment: @whuber By "enough to determine" I'm looking for a metric with I can say how much of the variance in my dependent variable is explained by my independent variables. I edited the question again, hopefully making this clearer. Thanks a lot for your help.